# Values of instance variables of superclass persist across instances of subclass

Tags: python, oop

I'm not sure if this is a fundamental misunderstanding on my part of the way that OOP in Python works, but I'm seeing some extremely strange behavior. Here's a code snippet:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, l = []):
        print "Foo1:", l
        self.mylist = l
        print "Foo2:", self.mylist

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, label=None):

        self.label = label
        super(Bar, self).__init__()
        print "Bar:", self.mylist



bar1 = Bar()
bar1.mylist.append(4)

bar2 = Bar()
print "bar2's list:", bar2.mylist
```

I expect that when `bar2` is constructed, its `mylist` instance variable will be set to the empty list. However, when I run this program in Python 2.6.6, I get the following output:

```
Foo1: []
Foo2: []
Bar: []
Foo1: [4]
Foo2: [4]
Bar: [4]
bar2's list: [4]
```

It looks like Foo's mylist instance variable is being persisted across multiple instances of the Bar class, but I have no idea why that would be. Any help you guys could give me would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that default parameters are bound at module initialization time, not at function invocation time, so there is only one default list that gets shared as the default for all invocations of that function.

What you really want to do is:

```
def __init__(self, l=None):
    if l is None:
        l = []
    self.mylist = l
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, they're bound at function definition time. That's the same as module initialisation time for module level functions and methods of module level classes, but will be later for classes and functions that are defined inside another function.

Comment: This is also why PyCharm will drop an 'orange' warning (i.e. do **NOT** do this) when a default parameter is mutable.

Answer (score 5):

Take a loot at [Python tutorial on default argument values](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values)
It says:

> *Important warning:* The default value is evaluated only once. This makes a difference when the default is a mutable object such as a list, dictionary, or instances of most classes.

or example, the following function accumulates the arguments passed to it on subsequent calls:

```
def f(a, L=[]):
    L.append(a)
    return L

print f(1)
print f(2)
print f(3)
```

This will print

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
```

If you don’t want the default to be shared between subsequent calls, you can write the function like this instead:

```
def f(a, L=None):
    if L is None:
        L = []
    L.append(a)
    return L
```