# numpy array subclass unexpedly shares attributes across instances

Tags: python, numpy

I am having a weird subclass numpy.ndarray issue that feels like
[Values of instance variables of superclass persist across instances of subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561294/values-of-instance-variables-of-superclass-persist-across-instances-of-subclass)
But I have not been able to understand fully or make it work for for my example.

Reading through 
[Slightly more realistic example - attribute added to existing array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#slightly-more-realistic-example-attribute-added-to-existing-array) I am trying to do pretty much exactly this. I want to add an attrs attribute to an array to hold information such as units in a dictionary.

Here is what I have:

```
import numpy
class dmarray(numpy.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array, attrs={}):
        obj = numpy.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        obj.attrs = attrs
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        # see InfoArray.__array_finalize__ for comments
        if obj is None:
            return
        self.attrs = getattr(obj, 'attrs', {})
```

So then to use it and demonstrate the issue

```
a = dmarray([1,2,3,4])
b = dmarray([1,2,3,4])
a.attrs['foo'] = 'bar'
print(b.attrs)
#{'foo': 'bar'}
b.attrs is a.attrs
# True  # hmm....
```

So b is picking up attrs that I don't want it to.  Annoyingly it works fine if you do this:

```
from datamodel import *
a = dmarray([1,2,3,4], attrs={'foo':'bar'})
b = dmarray([1,2,3,4])
b.attrs
# {}
```

So how in the world do I make this dmarray work how I want it to?

---

Edit:
OK so this seems to fix the problem but I don't understand why.  So lets change the question to what this is doing and why it works?

```
class dmarray(numpy.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array, attrs=None):
        obj = numpy.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        return obj

    def __init__(self, input_array, attrs=None):
        if attrs == None:
            attrs = {}
        self.attrs = attrs
```

So by removing the kwarg from `__new__()` and putting it in `__init__()` it works.  I just tried this as a "well it might work"

```
a = dmarray([1,2,3,4])
b = dmarray([1,2,3,4])
a.attrs['foo'] = 'bar'
b.attrs
# {}
```

Comment: A colleague mentioned that he thought the issue is probably .view(), hmm what else can I use there?

Comment: Sounds a bit like [this important warning](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values).

Comment: Thanks, The issue was certainly the attrs={} but manifested itself in a way I was not expecting and I kept looking at .copy()

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is here:

```py
def __new__(cls, input_array, attrs={})
```

Never do this `attrs={}` in a function header. The expected result is (probably) not what you think it is. This is a common Python Pitfall. See here [Default Parameter Values in Python](https://web.archive.org/web/20190320225317/http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm)

The right way how to do this:

```py
def __new__(cls, input_array, attrs=None):
    if attrs is None:
        attrs = {}
```

Comment: Right, this is the answer.  Look past .copy() and don't use the default in the way I did.  Thanks.

Comment: Or you can do like this: `attrs = attrs or {}`

Comment: @devxoul - cool idea, but that does not seem particularly safe to me. A lot of things are considered `False` in Python, are not they? I would not rely on that construction.

Comment: @Fenikso though to be fair if you pass in something else entirely into `attrs` it won't be considered `None` and the function will still fail because it will expect that `attrs` is a dictionary.

Comment: @Jonathan Well, that is not a problem. It is supposed to fail at that condition, as is any function expecting some parameter and getting something different. That is dynamic typing feature I would say. Of course, you can check for subclasses of `dict`, but I would say it is more Pythoniac to rely on duck typing.